# Algorithm for distribution people with voting options

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have `x` persons and `y` projects (`y >= x`).

Each person can vote for three different projects (first choice, ...). I'm searching for an algorithm who finds the distribution which is the best for everybody.

My first idea was to just calculate every possible distribution and implement a 'happiness score', so when a person get their first choice, three points added, second choice two points added, third choice one point added and then he gets a random project no point is added to the score. But quick I realized this will take some time to calculate every distribution when there is a higher number of persons and projects.

Is there any algorithm or programming approach that can solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: And, how is your decisions variables to generate the "happiness score"? Do you have some kind of data to do the analysis or do you apply over a specific statistical distribution bootstraped?

Comment: I don't quite have the time to write up a full answer to this, but it appears to be a form of a bipartite graph matching. We may be able to use any stable-matching algorithm, from [Gale-Shapely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Shapley_algorithm) to formulating it even as a [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) problem